# Android Proguard Error on debug build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I wanted to see Proguard in action on Debug build. Here's my build.gradle with Android Studio.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
```

My builds fail and I get this output:

```
:proguardDebug
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPreAuth: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPreAuth: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPreAuth: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPurchase: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPurchase: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: JavaAPI.CavvPurchase: can't find referenced class sun.misc.BASE64Decoder
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
:proguardDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':proguardDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you add progaurd? Is it a Maven repo?

Comment: Proguard is available in Android SDK tools/proguard. I see it there.